# CrossRider extension is not working on Internet Explorer 11, there is an error in the console

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser-extension, crossrider

We are using CrossRider to develop an extension for Internet Explorer. I installed our production extension, and I received this error in the console:

```
---- JS Exception from: Client ----
Error: 'appAPI' is undefined
Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error
Location: User Code
Line: 3
```

The extension is not doing anything except this error in the console. What is the problem?

By the way, it took a long time to install the extension, longer than usual.

Our Extension ID is 43889. I'm using Internet Explorer 11 but this extension should work on all versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: By the way, after I reinstalled the extension - it worked without problems.

Comment: I installed it and it worked fine as well. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]